# PostgreSQL create trigger: Syntax error on insert action

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-triggers

I want to create a trigger in PostgreSQL.

I have a products table and a categories table. If a new tuple is inserted into the products table with a category_id, which does not exist yet, I want to create a category with this exact category_id. I wrote some SQL code but I get a syntax error at "INSERT" at line 6.

My code is the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProductTrig
  AFTER INSERT ON products
  REFERENCING NEW ROW AS newrow
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (newrow.category_id NOT IN (SELECT category_id FROM categories))
  INSERT INTO categories (category_id) VALUES (newrow.category_id);
```

Does anybody see the problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: There are a couple problems here.  Firstly, you can't use an INSERT statement directly in a trigger.  You will need to create a trigger function first, and then get the trigger to call that.  Also, you can't use subqueries in your WHEN clause expression.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), you can see that the end of the statement must be EXECUTE PROCEDURE followed by a stored procedure name. In your query you specify an INSERT clause, which does not meet these requirements.

You'll need to frame your INSERT clause within a stored procedure and then refer to that at the end of your CREATE TRIGGER statement. The [documentation for CREATE PROCEDURE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) can help you there.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION insert_data()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM categories c WHERE c.category_id = OLD.category_id) THEN
      INSERT INTO categories(category_id, category_name) VALUES (OLD.category_id, 'Unknown');
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ProductTrig
  BEFORE INSERT ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_data();

When I now insert a product with a catID that does not exist, I get an error saying that the key is not in categories so I cannot create a product with this foreign key

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE), write a function to run after the trigger.

For example:

```sql
CREATE [ CONSTRAINT ] TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { event [ OR ... ] }
    ON table_name
    [ FROM referenced_table_name ]
    [ NOT DEFERRABLE | [ DEFERRABLE ] [ INITIALLY IMMEDIATE | INITIALLY DEFERRED ] ]
    [ REFERENCING { { OLD | NEW } TABLE [ AS ] transition_relation_name } [ ... ] ]
    [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
    [ WHEN ( condition ) ]
    EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )

where event can be one of:

    INSERT
    UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ]
    DELETE
    TRUNCATE
```